# Write An Annotation to Constrain Class/Method Naming in Java?

Tags: java, annotations, naming

I'm trying to find a way to use annotation to constrain namings in Java. Might be something looks like this:

```
@Getter
public String getXxx();
```

And when the method name does not meet the convention, for example not started with "get", the compiler will throw some error. So that during the coding progress in IDE, such like eclipse, the developer will be able to notice.

I'm getting some ideas from [this article](http://kingsfleet.blogspot.hk/2009/09/validating-annotations-at-compile-time.html), but it's too long and complex for me.

Any simpler examples or directions would be very nice.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the custom annotations guide [HERE](http://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/)

It also shows you how to use reflection to get info from the annotated elements, you could easily use this to fetch the method name and verify whether it meets your convention and take appropriate actions etc...

Comment: This is for using annotation during runtime, but I'm looking for a way to use it during compiling like a syntax checker. Like what I mentioned in my example, if a method with @Getter annotation was not named starting with "get", I want to see the little red cross at the left side by the line in eclipse..

Answer (score 0):

Didn't get to do it myself but it appears to be possible. You can do some [background reading](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/type_annotations.html) or go directly to the [3rd party tool](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/) they link.